# Adaptive design in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a custom table view cell:

[image]

There are 3 labels ( one, two, three accordingly ), and 2 images ( right and bottom ).

The bottom image is constrained to the bottom, left, right parent container edges to 0 - so that it would take 100% width and be always on bottom ( **works** ).

The right image has constrained width and height - so that it would be always same size 70x70, and constrained to left parent container edge and constrained in alignment vertical - so that it would remain in the middle left ( **works** )

The problem is with my labels:

They are constrained to the top and bottom edger of container, so they could stretch for entire height ( **works** )

But the problem is with their width - i want those 3 labels to take full width of the cell ( cell is designated for 500 px, but table view has changeable width ):

[image]

And second, third labels must be twice bigger than first.

**Proportions 1:2:2 - how to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these constraints (all multipliers are 1 except for #5)

1. Label1 leading space to its superview's leading edge
2. Label1 trailing space to Label2's leading edge
3. Label2 trailing space to Label3's leading edge
4. Label3 trailing space to RightImage's leading edge
5. Label1 equal width to Label2 (multiplier: 0.5 (or 2 if Label2 is the first item))
6. Label2 equal width to Label3

Then just resolve any misplaced views by updating their frames to match their constraints.

Here's an example xib (in source code format):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="5056" systemVersion="13D65" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3733"/>
        <capability name="Constraints with non-1.0 multipliers" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="Cell" rowHeight="71" id="Snt-TF-Qv9" userLabel="Table View Cell - Cell (frame: {0, 0, 500, 71})">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="500" height="71"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="Snt-TF-Qv9" id="ifW-8U-Dwt" userLabel="Content View - frame: {0, 0, 500, 70}">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="500" height="70"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ebK-KE-wKZ" userLabel="RightImage - frame: {430, 0, 70, 70}">
                        <rect key="frame" x="430" y="0.0" width="70" height="70"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="70" id="IJt-5U-cmM" userLabel="Width of 70"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="70" id="KLU-ff-5JU" userLabel="Height of 70"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </imageView>
                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label1" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="07L-x8-fgp" userLabel="Label1 - frame: {0, 0, 86, 70}">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="86" height="70"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label2" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TKJ-Pe-W0d" userLabel="Label2 - frame: {86, 0, 172, 70}">
                        <rect key="frame" x="86" y="0.0" width="172" height="70"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label3" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0cS-0h-VY6" userLabel="Label3 - frame: {258, 0, 172, 70}">
                        <rect key="frame" x="258" y="0.0" width="172" height="70"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="paS-mk-EO0" userLabel="BottomImage - frame: {0, 69, 500, 1}">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="69" width="500" height="1"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="1" id="UqL-XZ-Bqo" userLabel="Height of 1"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </imageView>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="paS-mk-EO0" secondAttribute="bottom" id="21O-zu-Ufa" userLabel="BottomImage bottom to superview bottom"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="07L-x8-fgp" secondAttribute="bottom" id="4dl-nF-vdx" userLabel="Label1 bottom to superview bottom"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="TKJ-Pe-W0d" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="0cS-0h-VY6" secondAttribute="width" id="Aln-95-m3O" userLabel="Label2 equal width to Label3 width"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="0cS-0h-VY6" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="TKJ-Pe-W0d" secondAttribute="trailing" id="CDV-tB-YBi" userLabel="Label2 trailing to Label3 leading"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="ebK-KE-wKZ" secondAttribute="centerY" id="CIO-EH-7R1" userLabel="RightImage centerY to superview centerY"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="paS-mk-EO0" secondAttribute="trailing" id="D4c-iR-zR6" userLabel="BottomImage trailing to superview trailing"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="ebK-KE-wKZ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="0cS-0h-VY6" secondAttribute="trailing" id="PAK-Kk-uLp" userLabel="Label3 trailing to RightImage leading"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ebK-KE-wKZ" secondAttribute="trailing" id="YVm-6s-8cL" userLabel="RightImage trailing to superview trailing"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="07L-x8-fgp" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="TKJ-Pe-W0d" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.5" id="Z0j-ak-yiS" userLabel="Label1 equal width to Label2 width (multiplier 0.5)"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="TKJ-Pe-W0d" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ifW-8U-Dwt" secondAttribute="top" id="b3m-Jy-1Q7" userLabel="Label2 top to superview top"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="TKJ-Pe-W0d" secondAttribute="bottom" id="dBA-LG-fEf" userLabel="Label2 bottom to superview bottom"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="07L-x8-fgp" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ifW-8U-Dwt" secondAttribute="top" id="g0E-cS-DWn" userLabel="Label1 top to superview top"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="0cS-0h-VY6" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ifW-8U-Dwt" secondAttribute="top" id="h1K-sO-uXk" userLabel="Label3 top to superview top"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="0cS-0h-VY6" secondAttribute="bottom" id="h4D-TA-lsH" userLabel="Label3 bottom to superview bottom"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="paS-mk-EO0" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ifW-8U-Dwt" secondAttribute="leading" id="hGy-Tw-hgS" userLabel="BottomImage leading to superview leading"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="07L-x8-fgp" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="TKJ-Pe-W0d" secondAttribute="leading" id="hVt-yJ-sJz" userLabel="Label1 trailing to Label2 leading"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="07L-x8-fgp" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ifW-8U-Dwt" secondAttribute="leading" id="iJX-3Z-bN4" userLabel="Label1 leading to superview leading"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Answer (score -2):

If it is a `UILabel` you are using then you could do something like this:

1. Make sure auto layout is off for the location holding your table view cell.
2. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you can add code like this:

   ```
   CGRect newFrame = cell.yourLabel.frame;

   newFrame.size.width = 500; 

   cell.yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
   ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP wants to use Auto Layout.